# DB not update without image in Insert command

Tags: php

In this code, if I doesn't upload the image then my Insert query doesnot work(if part not working).If I upload image then it's working(else part working ).

**CODE**

```
  if (isset($_POST['submit'])) {
            include('config.php');

            $Title = mysql_real_escape_string($_POST["Title"]);
            $Description = mysql_real_escape_string($_POST["description"]);
            $imageType = mysql_real_escape_string($_FILES["image"]["type"]);
            $DateTime = date('Y/m/d H:i:s');
            $Category = $_POST["select_category"];
   //This part is not Working(Below If Part )

            if(empty($_FILES["image"]["tmp_name"]) || !is_uploaded_file($_FILES["image"]["tmp_name"])) {
            mysql_query("INSERT INTO `News` VALUES('','$Title','$Description','$Category',1,'$DateTime',1)");
            echo "<a href=list.php><img src=../img/success.gif /><span>View List</span></a>";
            }
//This part working(below else Part)
            else
            { 
             $imageName = mysql_real_escape_string($_FILES["image"]["name"]);
             $imageData = mysql_real_escape_string(file_get_contents($_FILES["image"]["tmp_name"]));
             mysql_query("INSERT INTO `News` VALUES('','$Title','$imageName','$Description','$imageData','$Category',1,'$DateTime',1)");
             echo "<a href=list.php><img src=../img/success.gif /><span>View Listx</span></a>";
            }
//some code here
```

Can anyone help me to fix this issue? Thanks in advance.

Comment: Exactly the conditions are written to do the same job. What is the problem?

Comment: When i Submit without image.then it's not working..No error but not working

Comment: Why would you even want to perform a query if `$_FILES` is empty or isn't uploaded, in the first place? Just make it `die();` or something. Just reverse your conditionals.

Comment: @Fred-ii- File upload is not mandatory.

Comment: I'm confused. The part where you wrote `//This part is not Working` is it for the code above that which doesn't work, or below it?

Comment: If Part is not working / Else part is working

Comment: If part is Without image upload part.That's Not working(but it doesn't raise any error )

Comment: What I take from this is that you're trying to insert data if `$_FILES` is empty or is NOT uploaded. That's what I read from the code in there `if(empty($_FILES["image"]["tmp_name"]) || !is_uploaded_file($_FILES["image"]["tmp_name"]))`

Comment: Are you sure you didn't mean to write it as `if(!empty($_FILES["image"]["tmp_name"]) || is_uploaded_file($_FILES["image"]["tmp_name"]))` ?

Comment: Yes.but that's not working

Comment: @Fred-ii- In your second coding.then it's same the else part know.because then it asks to upload the file

Comment: I want If i doen't upload the file i need to do IF part... If i  upload the file i wanted to do ELSE part

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In part not working you must do follow syntax:

```
INSERT INTO table_name (column1,column2,column3,...)
VALUES (value1,value2,value3,...);
```

Comment: Id is autoincrement.then i need to mention Id as coloumn 1 ?

Comment: No you don't need to list what you don't want to write down in your code